# Screenshot of screen subregion using GTK

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to take screenshots of only part of the screen using Python under Ubuntu 10.04.

Here's my code (assume `IMAGE_GRAB` is False):

```
def screenshot_roi(regions):
    if IMAGE_GRAB:
        return map(ImageGrab.grab, regions)
    else:
        w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
        sz = w.get_size()
        pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
        src = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
        results = []
        for roi in regions:
            if not roi:
                results.append(None)
                continue
            x,y,width,height = roi
            dst = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,width,height)
            src.copy_area(x,y,width,height,dst,0,0)
            im = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", (width, height), dst.get_pixels())
            results.append(im)
        return results
```

Nothing that fancy here.  Captures the entire drawable into a pixel buffer, and then proceeds to crop each pixel buffer before converting it to the required PIL object.

This is the mainline:

```
def main():
    regions = [(845, 219, 248, 82), (1101, 243, 109, 59), 
               (1213, 245, 66, 57), (1281, 245, 74, 58)]    
    images = screenshot_roi(regions)
    for i,roi in enumerate(images):
        if roi:
            roi.save('%d.png' % i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The resulting images (all except for the first one) have stride issues, though:

1: [image] 
2: [image] 
3: [image] 
4: [image]

Now, if I do the cropping in PIL, everything works well:

```
def screenshot_roi(regions):
    if IMAGE_GRAB:
        return map(ImageGrab.grab, regions)
    else:
        w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
        sz = w.get_size()
        pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
        src = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
        entire_im = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", sz, src.get_pixels())
        results = []
        for roi in regions:
            if not roi:
                results.append(None)
                continue
            x,y,width,height = roi
            crop = entire_im.crop((x,y,x+width,y+height))
            crop.load()
            results.append(crop)
        return results
```

I don't want to do it this way, thought, because the conversion from GTK to PIL is quite expensive.  It's a waste because I'm converting the entire image just to get small sub-regions out of it.

Can anyone suggest why the GTK version is having stride errors?

*EDIT*

Working source:

```
x,y,w,h = region
win = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,w,h)
src = pb.get_from_drawable(win,win.get_colormap(),x,y,0,0,w,h)
im = PIL.Image.frombuffer('RGB', (w,h), src.get_pixels(), 'raw', 
                'RGB', src.get_rowstride(), 1)
return im
```

Comment: Not very pythonic, but you might want to use [`shutter`](http://shutter-project.org/): `shutter -s=X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT -e`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's because get_pixels returns you the data as it is stored in memory. What you're missing here is that a line may have some padding at the end of it, for performance reasons (because of memory alignment constraints).

See the [GdkPixbuf structure](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#image-data): the interesting information is the rowstride, which is the number of bytes between the start of a row and the start of the next row. It equals the number of data bytes + padding bytes in a row.

Beware that **the last line has no padding**.

Comment: You put me on the right track.  The buffer was the full size of the window, but I was handling it as if it was the same size as the required subregion.  Since I don't need anything outside the subregion, I fixed the problem by reducing the size of the buffer to the size of the subregion.